# Homebrew install package which then won't run

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh

I've installed homebrew and used it successfully for installing and using packages before. But when I installed a packaged called "shpotify" that can be used to control spotify from the command line, Homebrew installs it successfully, but then when I try to run it, I get an error "zsh: command not found: shpotify" Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Homebrew installs packages within their own containers then symlinks those files to the appropriate hierarchy within /usr/local or requires you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable answer:

The project is called shpotify.

The installed binary is called `spotify`

Use that as your command.